# Add custom functions for spreadsheet in my Google appscript addon not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently developing a Google appscript addon. It was already published into the Google Workspace Marketplace. I am trying to add some custom functions for spreadsheet in the script. For example, something like this:

```
  /**
  * Multiplies the input value by 2.
  *
  * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
  * @return The input multiplied by 2.
  * @customfunction
  */

  function DOUBLE(input) {
    return input * 2;
  }
```

But the function still doesn't show up when I put the function name in the cell after I deployed it. How to fix this?

I searched around, but still couldn't find the answer. I also checked Google [date_add_and_substract](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/tree/master/sheets/dateAddAndSubtract)

I see some Google Workspace addon supports these custom functions, not sure how they achieve it.

Thanks!